# Sorting by price with Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

As part of an ItemSearch operation with Amazon AWS, one can sort the results by price.  Does anyone know which actual price the sort is performed by?  Sale Price? Regular Price?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're sorting them in lowest-to-highest order, it lists them by the lowest available price per item.  There's list price, new price (sale price), and used price to choose from.  If I remember correctly, you can customize your query to include any or all of these prices. Whichever of these three is lowest determines the sort placement for an item.  See the results on [ThriftCart.com](http://www.thriftcart.com/) (generated by AWS query) for an example.